# My label is not updating when I change the StringVar() variable

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

For my program I am using a `StringVar()` variable to pass a value between screens meaning I can process some text and display it on the next "Screen".

**Full Program**
https://paste.ee/p/0gMqK

In this program I create a stringvariable called foo

```
    root=tk.Tk()
    foo=encrypted_message=tk.StringVar()
```

I then create a simple function with in the container class to add two entries together and then set the stringvar to the result

```
    def add(self,a,b):
        c=str(int(a)+int(b))
        foo.set(c)
        self.show_frame("Screen2")
```

I then call the command on screen 1

```
    button1=tk.Button(self,text="Lorem",command=lambda: controller.add(entry1.get(),entry2.get()))
```

I want to now change the label on screen 2 to the value of the string var() I set it to.

```
    label1=tk.Label(self,textvariable=foo)
```

When I run the program screen 2 is just a blank screen and the label text hasn't updated even though I changed the value of the stringvar

Full Program

```
    import Tkinter as tk
    class ProgramScreen(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
            container=tk.Frame(self)
            container.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
            self.frames={}
            self.foo=tk.StringVar()
            for F in (Screen1,Screen2):
                page_name=F.__name__
                frame=F(parent=container,controller=self)
                self.frames[page_name]=frame
                frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
                self.show_frame("Screen1")
        def show_frame(self,page_name):
            frame=self.frames[page_name]
            frame.tkraise()
        def add(self,a,b):
            c=str(int(a)+int(b))
            foo.set(c)
            self.show_frame("Screen2")
    class Screen1(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self,parent,controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
            self.controller=controller
            self.pack(fill="x",expand=1)
            entry1=tk.Entry(self)
            entry1.pack()
            entry2=tk.Entry(self)
            entry2.pack()
            button1=tk.Button(self,text="Lorem",command=lambda: controller.add(entry1.get(),entry2.get()))
                button1.pack()
    class Screen2(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self,parent,controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
            self.controller=controller
            self.pack(fill="x",expand=1)
            label1=tk.Label(self,textvariable=controller.foo.get())
            label1.pack()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = ProgramScreen()
        app.mainloop()
```

**--Edit--**

I have fixed the code to call the stringVar variable within the programScreen Class

Comment: You need to provide an [MCVE] not your 200-line code. Also, there are so many unnecessary comments on that full code.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong here, when I change the StringVar content using `encrypted_message.set('new text')`, it does update the label.

Comment: I have made a different example which gives me the same problem.

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce the problem. Please create a minimum, _complete_ example.

Comment: @BryanOakley paste.ee/p/0gMqK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one problem is that you are creating two instances of `Tk`. A tkinter program must have only one instance of `Tk`. If you need multiple windows, all windows except the first need to be instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: I couldn't work out where to define the string var within my instance of Tk created with the ProgramScreen Class

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I used the .get() function and also that I had called Tkinter correctly.